# Forward Search in FullText Search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I've implemented FullText Search using the `CONTAINS` clause provided by MS SQL.

If I search for `'Stac'` then I get `'Stack'` as a result. But if I search for `'tac'` then the database doesn't return any result.

```
SELECT * FROM TEMPTABLE WHERE CONTAINS(ColumnDetails, '"*tac*"'). This doesn't work.
```

How can I make this possible?

Comment: you **cannot** search for string with leading wildcard using the FTS. FTS **only** supports searching for `SomeText*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **LIKE** operator which can be useful to you. Below is the link.
[LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

E.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE '%AN%'
```

which would produce result like

```
store_name         Sales    Date
LOS ANGELES        $1500    Jan-05-1999
SAN DIEGO          $250 Jan-07-1999
SAN FRANCISCO      $300 Jan-08-1999
```

In the above example coulmn_name=store_name which fetched the result LOS ANGELES, SAN DiEGO, SAN Fran..

which contains **AN**.

Comment: But we have already impelemented Fulltext search catalogue and all the things. Can it be possible with full text search

Comment: @ArpanDesai: you **cannot** search for string with leading wildcard using the FTS. FTS **only** supports searching for `SomeText*`